# 'Generate Near Table' and 'XY To Line' Not Working As Expected

Tags: arcgis-pro

I have two point layers (layer-1 and layer-2).

- I used 'Generate Near Table' to identify connections between points in layer-1 and layer-2. I used a search radius of 5000m and maximum number of closest of 10.
- I then used the 'XY To Line' tool to create connection lines between the connections identified in the first step.

Issue: some points in layer-1 are connecting to less than 10 points in layer-2 although there are more layer-2 points within the 5000m radius.

In the attached image the three green lines are generated by ArcGIS and orange broken-lines are not generated but are within the 5000m radius.

What could be the reason and how do I correct this?

Software: ArcGIS Pro 2.6.0

[image]

Comment: You mention two tools but do not tell us whether the first appears to be working as documented. If it is then I think you should focus your question on what appears to be astray in the second tool. If not, then focus it on the first tool and forget about the second tool for now.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Issue was that there were duplicate points in my input data (point layer). Once the duplicates are removed the tools work as expected.